# Enemy Wave Spawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

very new to unity and not been doing this for long but decided to attempt a wave based spawning system without any tutorials (took the actual spawning from a tutorial though), didn't turn out too well and running the project seems to wait the spawnTick and then spawn an enemy, wait again and then spawns endlessly, not waiting at all for the wave cooldown. I'm not exactly sure what is causing this although I'm sure its just an oversight or me thinking something works a little differently. If someone could give some insight or tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
    public GameObject EnemyPrefab;
    public int waveNumber = 1;
    public int enemiesSpawned;
    public int spawnNumber;
    public int spawnCap = 25;
    public static int enemiesAlive;
    private WaitForSeconds spawnTick = new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    void Start()
    {
        spawnNumber = waveNumber * 5 + 10;
        StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemy());
    }
    void Update()
    {
        spawnNumber = waveNumber * 5 + 10;
        StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemy());
        if(enemiesAlive == 0) StartCoroutine(NextWave());
    }
    IEnumerator SpawnEnemy()
    {
        while(enemiesSpawned < spawnNumber && enemiesAlive < spawnCap)
        {
            yield return spawnTick;
            int randomNumber = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(0f, SpawnPoints.Length - 1));
            Instantiate(EnemyPrefab, SpawnPoints[randomNumber].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            enemiesAlive++;
            enemiesSpawned++;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator NextWave()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
        waveNumber++;
        enemiesSpawned = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok. So you wanted spawn all for wave. Wait. So next wave.  Your code reads wait a tick spawn an enemy repeat tbh im surprised it’s not gone nuts and slowed to 1fps as you call the spawn every frame. The yield needs to be outside the while. Also not called every frame otherwise it will keep re spawning enemies for each one you kill.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.